# TextView in Fragment "on a null object reference"

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a Fragment

```
public class Player extends Fragment {

private TextView songTitleLabel,songNameSinger;
private View view;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false);

    // All player buttons
    songTitleLabel = view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
    songNameSinger = view.findViewById(R.id.singer);
    return view;
}
```

and there is a method in the same fragment to do that

```
public void playSong(String id ,String Singer) {
   songTitleLabel.setText(id);
   songNameSinger.setText(Singer);       
}
```

and I call this method in the main activity

```
String name = CardList.get(position).getId();
String singer = CardList.get(position).getSinger();
Player player = new Player();
player.playSong(name,singer);
```

and I make sure this when the string goes to Fragment method it not become `null` so I put a Log and I see its `not null` but when I make the `TextView.setText` it come with this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

So I try another thing I set the value by myself like this

```
songTitleLabel.setText("Value");
```

and it did work, I don't know where the problem is...
Thanks guys...

Comment: Are you trying to call fragment method from Activity?

Comment: Would you mind providing the complete fragment and the part of the class that's calling the fragment method?

Comment: it is returning null because you are directly creating the new instance for fragment trying to access playSong(), Please check my answer it will solve your problem

Comment: have you assigned you CardList ? the problem is in ur cardList  or position variables so have you assigned them correctly?

Comment: @Badran its not the CardList because if it is i get null on the log too

Comment: @GaneshPatil i will try it

Comment: it will solve your null pointer issue

Comment: songTitleLabel.setText("Value");
 since this worked with you then the problem is with them  and it will show the error in textview since you are assigning null value to text view

Comment: @Badran he is trying to call fragment method from Activity by creating new object that's why he is getting null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only creating object of that `fragment` will not call the `oncreateview of that fragment`(where you initialize your views) so your `TextView` is *null*

Please call your fragment method from Activity like below example

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();


Player fragment = (Player )fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
fragment.playSong(name,singer);
```

OR

```
Player fragment = (Player ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.playSong(name,singer);
```

Comment: its comes with error inconvertible types; can't cast fragment to fragment.Player which in my case my fragment

Comment: pls post what are u trying?